# How to set up a taskbar in enlightenment DE?

Tags: desktop, desktop-environment, enlightenment

There is no taskbar in e17 and it is not comfortable to check and switch between open windows. While ibar module provides some limited functionality it shows only minimized windows. There was itask module, but it is discontinued as it seems. Is there any other way to set up a taskbar in e17?

Comment: Have you tried "Engage"?  I read it is meant as a replacement of "itask"...

Comment: no, thank you. Seems like Engage is a renamed itask module.

Comment: Ah, I see. Sorry.

Comment: @tasty: does it work?

Answer (score 1):

[`hpanel`](http://freecode.com/projects/hpanel) :-)

> ```
> hpanel(1)                        User Commands                       hpanel(1)
>
> NAME
>        hpanel - a minimalist panel for X
>
> SYNOPSIS
>          hpanel [options]
>
> DESCRIPTION
>        hpanel is a minimalist panel for X. Hpanel is version of fspanel
>        (handles maximized windows better). It contains a small panel that
>        lists windows and allows switching workspaces for use with a window
>        manager that supports NETWM specification. Known working window
>        managers are pekwm and aewm++.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

In the releases of e17 there is a module called tasks that provides a taskbar, all you need to do is enable that module and add it to your shelf.
In e19 the IBar module also performs everything you would expect from a taskbar so you can use that instead.